# Jira Data Extraction Rest API

Tags: python, rest, jira, jira-rest-api, atlassian-python-api

I want to extract data using python rest api, but it only allow 200 records at same time
is there any way to get all data in Jira que ?

Guessing an export to CSV then pull into excel for reporting might work?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use pagination https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/#pagination what are you using to make the requests? Your code you currently have would be helpful too

Answer (score 0):

Total 200 issues seems to be the default limit of Jira.

If you use any Python package to retrieve data from Jira over REST API, then the limit can be customized.

E.g. with [Jira package](https://pypi.org/project/jira/) you can do it simply this way:

```
from jira.client import JIRA
j = JIRA(options={"server": "https://myjira.domain.com"}, basic_auth=('username', 'password'))
issues = j.search_issues('issuetype = Epic', maxResults=1000)
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See more information in the documentation:
https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#searching